# How to add a Chain, Residues and atoms in pdb file?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, protein-database

I want to add a chain with all the residues and one carbon-alpha atom per residue using the OpenMM. Here the link of instances can be used [openMM documentation](http://docs.openmm.org/7.0.0/api-python/generated/simtk.openmm.app.topology.Topology.html#simtk.openmm.app.topology.Topology.addChain) . Currently I have one chain in my pdb file [pdb file](https://github.com/mahesh27dx/molecular_phys/blob/main/Worksheet8/CA_only.pdb). Here is what I've tried:

```py
from simtk.openmm.app import *
from simtk.openmm import *
from simtk.unit import *
import numpy as np
import mdtraj as md

# Here I remove all other atoms except carbon-alpha and stored them in a new file 'CA_only.pdb'
main_pdb = md.load_pdb('1PGB.pdb')
atoms_to_keep = [atom.index for atom in main_pdb.topology.atoms if atom.name == 'CA']
new_pdb = main_pdb.atom_slice(atoms_to_keep)
new_pdb.save('CA_only.pdb')

# Then I try to add a chain and residue, but no results
pdb = PDBFile('CA_only.pdb')
top = topology.Topology
chain=top.addChain(id='A')
residue = top.addResidue(MET, 0)
```

I might be using wrong names of residues. But I don't know what is wrong. Could someone have any idea how to resolve this? Thanks!!

Comment: You have way more imports present than are needed for your script. Without known the proper dependencies, it is hard to reproduce your problem. Please restrict your code to only the imports that are needed to execute this example.

Comment: What are the results of your script? Do you see any error messages? A `TypeError: addChain() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` for example?

Comment: @LydiavanDyke thanks for your response. I can do the same thing using mdtraj (md.topology.addChain()), but why in openMM I have to give positional argument.

Comment: shouldn't you have brackets after `topology.Topology`?